# Unclear why if statement doesn't work

Tags: objective-c

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work:

```
int nrSegments=[segment valueForKeyPath:@"iteneryLegs.@count"];
    if (0==nrSegments) {
        [self removeSegment:segment];
    }
```

but this does?

```
int nrSegments=[[segment valueForKeyPath:@"iteneryLegs] count];
    if (0==nrSegments) {
        [self removeSegment:segment];
    }
```

Comment: The second code sample won't even compile, it's missing a quote.  Can you paste in the exact code?

Comment: no the paste was not the exact code the quotes were there .. just pasted same code twine and made the change in the question.. small oops

Answer (score 2):

Because valueForKeyPath:@"iteneryLegs.@count" returns an NSNumber ?

Comment: So how would the if statement look if nrSegments is a NSNumber?

Comment: NSNumber *nrSegments=[[segment valueForKeyPath:@"iteneryLegs] count];
if([nrSegments intValue]==0){